# Which software can mount disk images created with Symantec's PGP Desktop 10?

Tags: disk-image, pgp

I have some disk images created with Symantec's (formerly RSA's) "PGP Desktop's PGPDisk [(Wikipedia article)](http://www.pgpi.didisoft.com/products/pgpdisk/)".
Is there some (preferably "free") software that can mount such images on Windows 10 and maybe Linux?

I found [PGPdisk](http://www.pgpi.didisoft.com/products/pgpdisk/), but the actual downloads seem to have gone away.

Answer (score 0):

would be great if you could share your experience, in case you found a solution in the meantime.
I own some .psd backup files from my old Win98 PC, and the only way I had to open those files was to install Win98 in VMware, and to install the latest free PGP disk, that I found here: https://www.pl.vim.org/pub/security/replay/pgp/pgp60/pgp651_freeware/PGP_pers_prv_651_eval.zip
(was very time consuming)
Linux and Mac versions also available there https://www.pl.vim.org/pub/security/replay/pgp/pgp60/pgp651_freeware/

Comment: Are you sure about the legal state of said software? AFAIK "PGP Disk" required a license. Is that an official build, or is it some hacked software?